# How CloudKit Sync with multiple devices?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, cloudkit

I have implemented cloud kit sync feature in my app, i am able to save, delete and update record into application.

Now my question is how can I handle it with multiple devices?

ex. User's A device has already signed with iCloud ID and entered 10 record and User's B device has not signed or no internet connection (my app support offline storage in CoreData) and entered some data into app (offline mode)

Now what should happen when user's B device signIn with iCloud ID and now what we can do here ?

Do i need to ask user to keep your local data or fetch from cloud data?

Is there any other standard way ?

Can any one help me to solve this puzzle. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This [Apple Document](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/MaintainingaLocalCacheofCloudKitRecords/MaintainingaLocalCacheofCloudKitRecords.html) may help you understanding the typical way.

I would suggest to keep Device B data, so here are the suggestion steps:

1. Sync data created in Device B to CloudKit
2. Fetch data available in CloudKit to Device B
3. Subscribe to future updates

By now, Device B and CloudKit should be in sync. If you have Device A subscribing to CloudKit updates correctly, Device A will receive the remote notification and fetch the latest updates. By then, Device A is in sync with CloudKit.